# Python: "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Questões:

1. **O que faz o trecho de código abaixo?** Nele está dando erro.
2. Como posso identificar e corrigir esse erro?

```
verificar = self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=None)
```

Ao rodar o código, apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Se eu retirar toda a parte do código abaixo, o programa roda normalmente.

> ```
>         for ix, val in enumerate(item):
>             col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
>             verificar = self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=None)
>             if verificar<col_w:
>                 self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=col_w)
> ```

O resultado será a imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
'''
Here the TreeView widget is configured as a multi-column listbox
with adjustable column width and column-header-click sorting.
'''
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MultiColumnListbox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        # s = "BANDO DE DADOS"
        #
        # msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
        #     padding=(10, 2, 10, 6), text=s)
        # msg.pack(fill='x')
        container = ttk.Frame()
        # container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        container.place(x=5, y=5, width=1170)

        # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=titulos_listbox, show="headings")
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
            command=self.tree.yview)
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
            xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in titulos_listbox:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in banco_dados:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value

            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                verificar = self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=None)
                if verificar<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=col_w)

def sortby(tree, col, descending):
    """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
    # grab values to sort
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
    #data =  change_numeric(data)
    # now sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))

# the test data ...

titulos_listbox = ['Data', 'Código', 'Item', 'Quantidade', 'Custo unitário', 'Custo total']
banco_dados = [
    ('01/01/2019', 123, 'teste1', 1, 10.0, 100.0, 'observação1'),
    ('02/01/2019', 456, 'teste2', 2, 20.0, 200.0, 'observação2'),
    ('03/01/2019', 789, 'teste3', 3, 30.0, 300.0, 'observação3')]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Multicolumn Treeview/Listbox")
    root["bg"] = "LightSteelBlue"
    root.geometry('1180x650+5+40')
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox()
    root.mainloop()

MultiColumnListbox()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na `verificar = self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=None)` o programa passa coluna por coluna buscando qual delas tem largura igual a nada para, no `if` seguinte, atribuir a largura de `col_w`.

```
[...]
if verificar<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(titulos_listbox[ix], width=col_w)
```

O erro de `index out of range` muito provavelmente está ocorrendo porque você manda analisar 6 colunas e só existem 5 delas declaradas, por exemplo. Você está se referindo a algo que não existe.

Comment: Ah. Obrigado. Compreendi. Na verdade, o programa verifica se o texto que está na coluna é maior que a coluna e, sendo maior, ele ajusta a largura da coluna. Na verdade ele faz essa verificação de forma invertida, verificando se a largura "None" é menor que "col-w", sendo menor, ele ajusta para "col_w".